# Storage Quota changes

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-developer

Earlier in office 365, the site collection storage quota was specified in MB, but now it is changed to GB and also it does not allow to make storage in decimal i.e 1.2 GB or 0.5 GB.

Can anyone please provide Microsoft link about it?

Thanks in advance.

[image: GB]

[image: MB]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find an exact release note, but this guy is from Microsoft and is authorized to comment on it.

https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/355859

Answer (score 2):

The Powershell commandlets still use MB, so you could always use

```
Set-SPOSite -Identity https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site -StorageQuota 12000
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161394.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks Eric for the info. But actually I am using CSOM to create site collection.